# how to make @OneToMany Relationship and which is best way to achieve OneToMany mapping?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many

How can we achieve `@OneToMany` Relationship in spring,hibernate? Scenario is likewise:

There are two classes `UserService` And `UserRole` According To my logic ,i'm fetching data from `UserRepository` By doing `@OneToMany` Relationship With `UserRoleService`

In RestFull Api's

There are two Models
1. `User` Model
2. `UserRole` Model

User.java(model):

```
User{
    private long userId

    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "userRoleId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    List<UserRole> userRoles;
}
```

UserRole.java(model)

```
UserRole{
    Long userRoleId;
}
```

My question i need my output  somewhat like

In User Table-:

```
UserId  title
1       A
2       S
3       B
```

in UserRole Table:

```
UserRoleId    Region 
1             china
2             USA
3             Japan
1             INDIA
```

So I need output somewhat type suppose regarding Id 1 in User Table

```
Output-:
1             A
1             INDIA
1             china
```

Please Help

Comment: Hello, your question is not clear. What is the problem with your `@OneToMany` relationship ? In your expected output, `A` seems to coming from `User Table` but `INDIA` and `china` seem to coming from `Region` in `UserRole`. I think you have problem with data representation.

Comment: What, exactly, is your question?

Comment: hi Alan Hay  I want to do @OneToMany With  above shown  output i have to achieve somewhat type that in user regarding UserRole